# RedirectToAction is not working in ActionResult

Tags: c#, json, model-view-controller

```
public ActionResult UploadImage(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{           
     if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
     {
          try
          {
              string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images"),
                    Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
              file.SaveAs(path);
              ViewBag.FileStatus = "File uploaded successfully";
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              ViewBag.FileStatus = "ERROR:" + ex.Message.ToString();
          }
     }
     else
     {
            ViewBag.FileStatus = "You have not specified a file.";
     }
 
     return Json("No files selected.", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Second `ActionResult` `PhysicianBiodata()`

```
public ActionResult PhysicianBiodata (int? Id)
{
    PhysicianBiodata newForm = new PhysicianBiodata();
    if (Id <= 0 || Id == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("UploadImage", "ServiceCompendium", 
                {HttpPostedFileBase httpPostedFileBase});
    }
    else
    {
        newForm = compendiumData.GetPhysicianBiodatas().Where(x => x.ID == Id)
                 .FirstOrDefault();
    }
    return View(newForm);
}
```

and  I want to call this `UploadImage()` into `PhysicianBiodata()` but its not working. Can you please help me....

Comment: Tell us what is not working specifically. The parameter?

Comment: It is giving 5 errors like;{}etc  around the parameter.

Comment: Make sure you having the right opening and closing `{ }` and `;`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you fix the last argument to the redirect?

Something like

```
return RedirectToAction("UploadImage", "ServiceCompendium", { new @file =httpPostedFileBase});
```

Also, where is httpPostedFileBase in the PhysicianBiodata method?

Comment: Is it even possible to redirect POST request to another POST action?

Comment: return RedirectToAction("UploadImage", "ServiceCompendium", {new @file= HttpPostedFileBase});
 is not working. I need to upload photo so thats wehy i am calling this function. Not sure where i am doing wrong.. Please help.

Comment: getting same parenthesis, semi-colon error around this httppostedfilebase